# Ordenando um array de objetos por data

Tags: javascript, data

Bom estou com um array de objetos e preciso ordenar a mais perto de hoje para mais longe de hoje. Por exemplo hoje é dia 24/11/2015 ai tenho em meu array as datas:

```
30/11/2015 
27/11/2015
25/11/2015
30/11/2015
```

No caso o resultado que estou precisando é que estás datas venham assim:

```
25/11/2015
27/11/2015
30/11/2015
30/11/2015
```

Dentro do meu array posso data, nome, e telefone.

Tentei utilizar o `sort()` dentro deste array porem não funcionou. Na verdade não entendo muito bem por `sort()`

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/527263/112052

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Adaptei essa [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value-in-javascript) a sua necessidade, você pode criar uma função própria e passá-la como parâmetro da função `sort`.

Veja Funcionando.

```js
    var objeto = [ 
    { data : new Date('11-30-2015'), nome: 'Marconi', telefone:'32486745425'},
    { data : new Date('11-31-2015'), nome: 'Marcos', telefone:'32486745425'},
    { data : new Date('11-25-2015'), nome: 'B', telefone:'32486745425'},
    { data : new Date('11-27-2015'), nome: 'Testes', telefone:'32486745425'},
];
            
function compare(a,b) {
  return a.data < b.data;
}

console.log(objeto.sort(compare));
```

Comment: seu código está fazendo a ordenação da menor para a maior data, e outra, se você adicionar uma data com mês diferente, só está considerando o dia, pois vocês está usando `string` :)

Comment: @PedroCamaraJunior resposta corrigida, obrigado pela dica.

Comment: Apesar de bem votada essa resposta está equivocada, a [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#:~:text=compareFn(a%2C%20b)%20return%20value) informa que o retorno para a função critério de classificação para `(a,b)`  deve ser `>0` para ordenar `a` após `b`, `==0` para manter as posições de `a` e `b` e deve ser `<0` para ordenar `a` ates de `b`.

Answer (score 5):

Duas das respostas atuais ([esta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/100076/112052) e [esta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/100074/112052)) estão usando os operadores `>` e `<` na função de *callback* passada para `sort`.

Mas isso pode não funcionar sempre, pois segundo a [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), a função funciona assim: ela recebe dois valores (`a` e `b`), e se `a` for "menor" (se deve estar antes de `b`), retorna um número negativo. Se `a` for "maior" (deve estar depois de `b`), retorna um número positivo. E se forem iguais (tanto faz a ordem entre eles), retorna zero. **Por isso que usar `>` ou `<` não adianta, pois o retorno desses operadores é apenas `true` ou `false` (só 2 valores), mas a função tem 3 retornos possíves**. [Aqui](https://ideone.com/9ugiOh) e [aqui](https://ideone.com/BTW8QD) - e também no *snippet* abaixo - você pode ver como não funciona:

```js
function compareErrado(a, b) {
    return a > b;
}

// se a é menor que b, retorna um número negativo
// se a é maior que b, retorna um número positivo
// se forem iguais, retorna zero
function compareCerto(a, b) {
    return a - b;
}

console.log([7, 6, 2, 3, 8, 4, 1, 5].sort(compareErrado));
console.log([7, 6, 2, 3, 8, 4, 1, 5].sort(compareCerto));

console.log([ new Date('2015-11-30'),
              new Date('2015-11-27'),
              new Date('2015-11-25'),
              new Date('2015-11-30') ].sort(compareErrado));
console.log([ new Date('2015-11-30'),
              new Date('2015-11-27'),
              new Date('2015-11-25'),
              new Date('2015-11-30') ].sort(compareCerto));
```

Portanto, para funcionar corretamente a função passada para `sort` deve fazer o que foi sugerido em [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/353139/112052) (que é o mesmo que a função `compareCerto` faz acima).

> Vale lembrar que em alguns browsers, a implementação errada pode funcionar às vezes (no Safari e Firefox "funcionou", no Chrome e [no Node.js](https://ideone.com/pWVZUt) não alterou a ordem dos elementos; não testei em outros *engines*). Mas se "funcionar", será por coincidência, pois a única forma garantida que funciona em todos os ambientes/browsers/engines é impĺementar corretamente, tratandos os três casos possíveis.

**Isso deveria ser o suficiente, mas ainda tem outro detalhe**: repare que no código acima eu usei o formato "aaaa-mm-dd" para criar as datas. Mas outras respostas usaram "dd-mm-aaaa", que nem sempre funciona. Por exemplo, no Chrome, `new Date('12-01-2018')` cria uma data referente a **1 de dezembro** (e não 12 de janeiro, que seria o "esperado"). Ou seja, além de não ordenar direito, ainda criou as datas erradas.

Já tem bastante coisa a respeito disso no site ([aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/456089/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/455437/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/408160/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/416172/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/469717/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/344030/112052)), mas basicamente, o único formato que é garantido pela especificação da linguagem que funciona em todos os ambientes é o definido pela [norma ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) (no caso, o formato "aaaa-mm-dd" que usei acima). Qualquer outro formato pode ou não funcionar.

Answer (score 2):

```js
var teste = [{
    nome: "pedro",
    data: new Date('11-30-2018')
  },
  {
    nome: "joao",
    data: new Date('12-01-2018')
  },
  {
    nome: "maria",
    data: new Date('10-05-2018')
  }
];

function ordemDecrescente(a, b) {
  return a.data - b.data;
}

function ordemCrescente(a, b) {
  return b.data - a.data;
}

teste.sort(ordemCrescente);

console.log(teste);

var points = [40, 100, 1, 5, 25, 10];
console.log(points.sort(function(a, b) {
  return b - a
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

> Realizei alguns testes com a função e estava realizando a ordenação
> errada, pois a data era string. para funcionar corretamente, você deve
> utilizar uma variável do tipo `Date`

Você pode usar o `sort()` mesmo, ela aceita como parâmetro opcional uma função, veja um exemplo.

```js
var teste = [
        { nome: "pedro", data: new Date('11-30-2015') },
        { nome :"joao", data: new Date('12-01-2015') },
        { nome: "maria", data: new Date('10-05-2015') }
    ];

function ordemDecrescente(a, b) {
    return a.data < b.data;
}

function ordemCrescente(a, b) {
    return a.data > b.data;
}
    
teste.sort(ordemDecrescente);

console.log(teste);
```

Comment: não entendi pq todas as respostas fazem uso de `if (a.data > b.data) return 1; if (a.data < b.data) return -1; return 0;` ao invés de apenas `return a.data > b.data;`

Comment: Pois é @TobyMosque fica bem melhor mesmo. Vou mudar aqui, valeu pela dica.

Comment: @TobiasMesquita Sei que já faz tempo que foi respondido, mas enfim. A [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) diz que a função recebe dois valores (`a` e `b`), e se `a` for "menor" (se deve estar antes de `b`), retorna um número negativo. Se `a` for "maior" (deve estar depois de `b`), retorna um número positivo. E se forem iguais (tanto faz a ordem entre eles), retorna zero. Por isso que usar `>` ou `<` não adianta, pois o retorno dos operadores é apenas `true` ou `false` (só 2 valores), mas a função tem 3 retornos possíves.

Comment: @TobiasMesquita Usar `>` ou `<` pode até funcionar em alguns casos, mas será por coincidência, e em muitos casos vai falhar, [veja este exemplo](https://ideone.com/9ugiOh) (não usei datas só pra ficar mais simples, mas veja que não funciona com datas também: https://ideone.com/BTW8QD). Apenas retornando os 3 valores distintos, é garantido que a ordenação fique correta.

Comment: Apesar de bem votada essa resposta está equivocada, a [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#:~:text=compareFn(a%2C%20b)%20return%20value) informa que o retorno para a função critério de classificação para `(a,b)`  deve ser `>0` para ordenar `a` após `b`, `==0` para manter as posições de `a` e `b` e deve ser `<0` para ordenar `a` ates de `b`.

Answer (score 0):

Usei isso uma vez:

```
function date_compare($a, $b)
{
    $t1 = strtotime($a['datetime']);
    $t2 = strtotime($b['datetime']);
    return $t1 - $t2;
}    
usort($array, 'date_compare');
```

`usort` — Ordena um array pelos valores utilizando uma função de comparação definida pelo usuário.

A função pega dois registros do `array` por vez e compara, se iguais retorna zero; se maior, numero positivo; e se menor, número negativo. 
O `usort` usa esse resultado para ordenar o array.

Retirado do SOEn: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910611/php-sort-a-multidimensional-array-by-element-containing-date

Comment: Tem como explicar ?

Comment: O usuário mandou PHP na pergunta cujo a tag é [tag:javascript].