# Problemas com array.sort()

Tags: javascript

Estou tentando ordenar um array porém estou tendo problema, ele so está retornando 0. Estou fazendo o seguinte:

Aqui eu sorteio meu array:

```
arrayVelho.sort(compare);
```

Após chamo a função compare que compara os dados do array:

```
function compare(a,b) {

//return a.TXT_NOMEX_PESSO < b.TXT_NOMEX_PESSO;
var valorA = ((a.TXT_NOMEX_PESSO == null)? "Z": a.TXT_NOMEX_PESSO),
    valorB = ((b.TXT_NOMEX_PESSO == null)? "Z": b.TXT_NOMEX_PESSO);

var respA = valorA.toUpperCase(),
    respB = valorB.toUpperCase();

        console.log(respA + " - " + respB);
    console.log(respA.TXT_NOMEX_PESSO > respB.TXT_NOMEX_PESSO ? -1 : respA.TXT_NOMEX_PESSO < respB.TXT_NOMEX_PESSO ? 1 : 0);
    return respA.TXT_NOMEX_PESSO > respB.TXT_NOMEX_PESSO ? -1 : respA.TXT_NOMEX_PESSO < respB.TXT_NOMEX_PESSO ? 1 : 0;
}
```

O resultado dos console.log() está assim:

```
HADAILTON DE SOUSA CARVALHO - RENAN RODRIGUES MORAES main.js:1350
0 main.js:1351
RENAN RODRIGUES MORAES - TESTESS main.js:1350
0 main.js:1351
TESTESS - ANTONIO main.js:1350
0 main.js:1351
ANTONIO - BACHINHO main.js:1350
0 main.js:1351
BACHINHO - CASA DE CARNE main.js:1350
0
```

A Estrutura de meu array é:

```
arrayVelho[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]

0: Object
COD_IDENT_PESSO: "3"
FLG_IDENT_PESSO: "L"
FLG_STATU_PESSO: "A"
TXT_NOMEX_PESSO: "HADAILTON DE SOUSA CARVALHO"
---------------
1: Object
COD_IDENT_PESSO: "4"
FLG_IDENT_PESSO: "M"
FLG_STATU_PESSO: "A"
TXT_NOMEX_PESSO: "RENAN RODRIGUES MORAES"
---------------
2: Object
COD_IDENT_PESSO: "3160127100149523"
FLG_IDENT_PESSO: "M"
FLG_STATU_PESSO: "A"
TXT_NOMEX_PESSO: "testess"
_---------------
3: Object
COD_IDENT_PESSO: "3160127100725576"
FLG_IDENT_PESSO: "M"
FLG_STATU_PESSO: "A"
TXT_NOMEX_PESSO: "Antonio"
----------------
4: Object
COD_IDENT_PESSO: "3160127100908469"
FLG_IDENT_PESSO: "M"
FLG_STATU_PESSO: "A"
TXT_NOMEX_PESSO: "bachinho"
----------------
5: Object
COD_IDENT_PESSO: "3160127100924955"
FLG_IDENT_PESSO: "M"
FLG_STATU_PESSO: "A"
TXT_NOMEX_PESSO: "casa de carne"
```

Ele deve ficar ordenado Alfabeticamente, Não tenho como prever, pois este array é de todas pessoas, pode ter 5 pessoas como pode ter 20.

O que estou fazendo de errado ? E como colocar em ordem Alfabética ?

Comment: Não seria essa mesma resposta? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/100068/ordenando-um-array-de-objetos-por-data

Comment: Não aquela eu ja consegui, tentei adapta-la para algo referente a nome, não data

Comment: Tem como você postar a estrutura do seu array?

Comment: sim, so um minuto

Comment: Se possível a ordem que ele deveria sair.

Comment: @Marconi Atualizei minha pergunta

Comment: Postei uma resposta Renan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ele não consegue ordenar de maneira correta quando tem valores maiúsculos e minúsculos.

Então basta você usar a função `toUpperCase()`para colocar todo o texto em `Maiúsculo` e comparar, ou caso queira usar `toLowerCase()`que torna todo o texto `Minúsculo`. Essa pergunta segue a mesa linha de raciocínio [dessa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/100068/ordenando-um-array-de-objetos-por-data)  resposta bastando apenas adaptar. Veja:

```js
var array = [ 
    {TXT_NOMEX_PESSO: 'HADAILTON DE SOUSA CARVALHO'},
    {TXT_NOMEX_PESSO: 'RENAN RODRIGUES MORAES'},
    {TXT_NOMEX_PESSO: 'testess'},
    {TXT_NOMEX_PESSO: 'Antonio'},
    {TXT_NOMEX_PESSO: 'bachinho'},
    {TXT_NOMEX_PESSO: 'casa de carne'}
];
    
function compare(a,b) {
  return a.TXT_NOMEX_PESSO.toUpperCase() > b.TXT_NOMEX_PESSO.toUpperCase();
}

console.log(array.sort(compare));
```

Comment: So precisei fazer uma mudança em seu código. Troquei return a.TXT_NOMEX_PESSO.toUpperCase() > b.TXT_NOMEX_PESSO.toUpperCase(); Por return a.TXT_NOMEX_PESSO.toUpperCase() < b.TXT_NOMEX_PESSO.toUpperCase();

Comment: @RenanRodrigues que bom que pude ajudar.