# Ordenar Vetor crescentemente com Angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

```
$scope.auxiliar.minimo = $scope.blocos[i].tamanhoTotal - processo.tamanho;
$scope.auxiliar.posicaoBlocoLivre = $scope.blocos[i];
$scope.menores.push($scope.auxiliar);
```

Eu quero ordenar o meu vetor "menores" crescentemente pelo atributo do objeto: `"$scope.auxiliar.minimo"`

Comment: Vê essa função se te ajuda: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy

Comment: Já tentou algo do tipo: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/100068/ordenando-um-array-de-objetos-por-data/100076#100076

Answer (score 1):

Segue uma forma de organizar o array para uso no JS criando uma função para ser passada como parâmetro no sort.

```
var sortByMinimo = function(a, b) {
    if (a.minimo < b.minimo) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (a.minimo > b.minimo) {
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
};
$scope.menores.sort(sortByMinimo);
```

Você pode usar os meios do AngularJs sugeridos na outra resposta, principalmente se você quer apenas organizar na view.

Answer (score 0):

Caso seu objetivo final seja mostrar na tela através da diretiva `ng-repeat` você pode ordenar diretamente durante o processo deste jeito:

```
<tr ng-repeat="menor in menores | orderBy:'-minimo'"></tr>
```

Ou através do serviço [$filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy)

```
$scope.menores = $filter('orderBy')($scope.menores, '-minimo');
```

lembrando que o sinal de + ou - prefixado à propriedade utilizada para ordenar significa ascendente ou descendente respectivamente.