# Organizar array de objetos de acordo com um de seus atributos

Tags: javascript, jquery

Bom, é como o título disse, gostaria de saber se teria como eu organizar um `array` de objetos de forma crescente de acordo com o valor de um atributo dado a ele.

**Exemplo:**

```
var objetos = []

var objeto1 {id:gerarId(), nome: nome1, idade: idade1}

var objeto2 {id:gerarId(), nome: nome2, idade: idade2}

objetos.push(objeto1);

objetos.push(objeto2);
```

E tipo agora eu queria o organizar em ordem crescente de acordo com o valor da idade.

Detalhe: Estou usando o `localstorage` para armazenar os dados, e quero fazer tudo em javascript.

Comment: Creio que o que você queira seja isto daqui https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/100068/ordenando-um-array-de-objetos-por-data/100076#100076

Answer (score 2):

Você deve passar uma função de comparação como parametro de `sort`:

```
objetos.sort(function(a, b) {
    return parseInt(a.idade) - parseInt(b.idade);
});
```

Referência: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979256/sorting-an-array-of-javascript-objects