# Como ordenar um array de datas no formato MM/YYYY

Tags: javascript, string, data

Eu preciso organizar um array de datas em ordem crescente, estou utilizando um código que já utilizo para ordernar uma lista de datas, porém dessa vez o formato é `MM/YYYY`.

Estou utilizando o código abaixo:

```
uniqueDates = ['5/2021', '9/2021', '12/2021', '8/2021'];

uniqueDates.sort(function(a, b){
  var aa = a.split('/').reverse().join(),
      bb = b.split('/').reverse().join();
  return aa < bb ? -1 : (aa > bb ? 1 : 0);
});
```

O retorno está sendo:

```
uniqueDates = ['12/2021', '5/2021', '8/2021', '9/2021']
```

Eu preciso do retorno desse modo:

```
uniqueDates = ['5/2021', '8/2021', '9/2021', '12/2021']
```

Como resolver esse problema? Por que ele ocorre?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O problema é a ordenação lexicográfica, que ocorre ao se utilizar os operadores relacionais com strings.

Vejamos para o caso em que `a` seria `12/2021` e `b` seria `5/2021`. Você teria um `aa` definido como `2021,12` e `2021,5` (resultado da reversão e junção, que por padrão utiliza a vírgula como separador).

Ao comparar o prefixo comum, `"2021,"`, temos uma igualdade. O problema ocorre quando vai comparar as strings `"12"` e `"5"`. Numericamente falando, 12 é maior que 5, mas a string `"12"` é menor do que `"5"`. Veja:

```js
console.log("12" < "5"); // true
```

Isso acontece porque a comparação de strings [é feita caractere a caractere](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/440496/112052), seguindo a **[ordem lexicográfica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order)**. Portanto, uma forma de resolver é garantir que os meses antes de outubro sejam prefixados com `"0"`, assim:

```js
const uniqueDates = ['5/2021', '9/2021', '12/2021', '8/2021'];

function formatYearMonthPad(dateStr) {
  return dateStr.split('/')
    .reverse()
    .map((part) => part.padStart(2, '0'))
    .join();
}

uniqueDates.sort(function(a, b) {
  const aa = formatYearMonthPad(a);
  const bb = formatYearMonthPad(b);
  return aa < bb ? -1 : (aa > bb ? 1 : 0);
});
console.log(uniqueDates);
```

Veja que agora não comparamos mais `"12"` com `"5"`, mas sim `"12"` com `"05"`. A comparação lexicográfica torna-se, então, fidedigna ao numeral correspondente.

---

Uma outra maneira seria construir uma nova instância de `Date` passando somente mês e ano pelo construtor e comparar o retorno de `getTime`, assim:

```js
const uniqueDates = ['5/2021', '9/2021', '12/2021', '8/2021'];

function extractYearAndMonthIndex(dateStr) {
  const [m, y] = dateStr.split('/').map((x) => parseInt(x, 10));
  return [y, m - 1];
}

uniqueDates.sort(function(a, b) {
  const aa = extractYearAndMonthIndex(a);
  const bb = extractYearAndMonthIndex(b);
  return new Date(...aa).getTime() - new Date(...bb).getTime();
});
console.log(uniqueDates);
```

Veja na documentação que o construtor `new Date` aceita vários formatos como *input*. Nesse caso, utilizamos somente o ano e *índice do mês* como argumentos.

No entanto, eu acho a comparação lexicográfica mais simples.

Answer (score 5):

> Os problemas do seu código já estão explicados na [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/527265/112052) então não vou repetir. Enfim, segue abaixo uma alternativa.

---

Em vez de transformar a string em outra, você pode simplesmente extrair os valores numéricos do mês e ano e compará-los diretamente:

```js
var uniqueDates = ['5/2021', '9/2021', '12/2021', '8/2021'];

uniqueDates.sort(function (a, b) {
    var [a_mes, a_ano] = a.split('/').map(val => parseInt(val));
    var [b_mes, b_ano] = b.split('/').map(val => parseInt(val));
    // primeiro compara o ano
    var cmp = a_ano - b_ano;
    if (cmp === 0) { // se o ano é igual, compara o mês
        cmp = a_mes - b_mes;
    }
    return cmp;
});

console.log(uniqueDates);
```

Assim, primeiro eu comparo o ano. Se o ano for igual, aí eu desempato comparando o mês (se o ano for diferente, eu nem comparo o mês, pois nesse caso não precisa).

Claro que se tivessem mais campos a serem comparados (dia, hora, minuto, etc), aí compensaria mais criar um `Date` ou reformatar a string (como já citado na [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/527265/112052)) em vez de comparar os campos um a um.

Answer (score 3):

Como os problemas com o código da pergunta já foram [explicados nessa outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/527265/112052):

> O problema é a ordenação lexicográfica, que ocorre ao se utilizar os
> operadores relacionais com strings....

Sigo com outra alternativa utilizando o método [`Date.UTC()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC) que retorna o número de milissegundos, de uma data, desde 1º de janeiro de 1970, 00:00:00 UTC.

O método `Date.UTC()` tem a seguinte assinatura:

***`Date.UTC(ano, mês[, dia[, hora[, minuto[, segundo[, milisegundo]]]]])`***

O algoritmo consiste em apenas obter de duas datas o número de milissegundos decorridos desde [Epoch Time](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Era_Unix) e os subtrair e usar esse valor como resultado para a função de comparação passada ao método [`Array.prototype.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) que ordena dois valores `a` e `b` segundo os seguintes critérios:

- Se `funcaoDeComparacao(a, b)` for menor que 0, ordena `a` para um índice anterior a `b`.
- Se `funcaoDeComparacao(a, b)` retornar 0, deixa `a` e `b` inalterados em relação um ao outro, mas ordenado em relação a todos os outros elementos.
- Se `funcaoDeComparacao(a, b)` é maior que 0, ordena `b` para um índice anterior que `a`.

```js
uniqueDates = ['5/2021', '9/2021', '12/2021', '8/2021'];

uniqueDates.sort((a, b) =>
  Date.UTC(...a.split('/').map(s => parseInt(s)).reverse()) -
  Date.UTC(...b.split('/').map(s => parseInt(s)).reverse())
);

console.log(uniqueDates);
```

### Edit:

Como [Luiz Felipe](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/69296/luiz-felipe) lembrou [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/527263/como-ordenar-um-array-de-datas-no-formato-mm-yyyy/527330?noredirect=1#comment956170_527330):

> ...assim como o construtor Date, a função Date.UTC espera o mês
> começando como 0 e terminando em 11. Então passar 12 consideraria
> janeiro do ano seguinte...

Então basta trazer os valores dos meses para o intervalo adequado.

```js
uniqueDates = ['5/2021', '9/2021', '12/2021', '8/2021'];

uniqueDates.sort((a, b) =>
  Date.UTC(...a.split('/').map((s, i) => parseInt(s) + (i == 0 ? -1 : 0)).reverse()) -
  Date.UTC(...b.split('/').map((s, i) => parseInt(s) + (i == 0 ? -1 : 0)).reverse())
);

console.log(uniqueDates);
```

Comment: Boa resposta. Nesse caso acho que não faz muita diferença, já que o intuito é só a ordenação; mas acho importante comentar que, assim como o construtor `Date`, a função `Date.UTC` espera o mês começando como 0 e terminando em 11. Então passar 12 consideraria janeiro do ano seguinte. Enfim, as APIs bizarras do JS...

Comment: @LuizFelipe, post editado segundo suas orientações.