# Ordenação de log por data

Tags: javascript, array, data

Estou querendo apresentar um log na tela, porém queria ordenar pela data, para que o com a data mais recente aparecesse em cima. Esses são os dados:

```
export const listarLog =  
    [
      {
          "data": "2022-05-01",
          "time": "08:00:00",
          "type": "DEBUG",
          "mensagem": "minha mensagem"
      },
      {
          "data": "2022-05-02",
          "time": "08:06:00",
          "type": "INFO",
          "mensagem": "minha mensagem de info"
      },
      {
          "data": "2022-05-02",
          "time": "08:07:00",
          "type": "ERRO",
          "mensagem": "minha mensagem de teste"
      }
  ];
```

Vi que deveria formatar essa data da seguinte forma:

```
  function dataFormat(d){
   
    var d_split = d.split("/");
    var dia = d_split[0];
    var mes = d_split[1]-1;
    var ano = d_split[2];
 
    return [dia,mes,ano];
 }
```

Porém não consegui prosseguir com a ordenação por data e hora utilizando `sort(),`.

Conseguem me ajudar?

Comment: Opa, aqui te ajudar? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/100068/ordenando-um-array-de-objetos-por-data/100076#100076

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para isso pode usar o método [`Sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

Como a sua data está no formato AAAA-MM-DD, basta converter para `Date()` antes, assim:

```js
const listarLog =  
    [
      {
          "data": "2022-06-01",
          "time": "08:00:00",
          "type": "DEBUG",
          "mensagem": "minha mensagem"
      },
      {
          "data": "2020-05-02",
          "time": "08:06:00",
          "type": "INFO",
          "mensagem": "minha mensagem de info"
      },
      {
          "data": "2022-04-02",
          "time": "08:07:00",
          "type": "ERRO",
          "mensagem": "minha mensagem de teste"
      }
  ];


listarLog.sort(function(a, b) {
  // aqui vai converter "data" para um object Date
  // a seguir "vê qual é maior"
  return (new Date(a.data) - new Date(b.data));
});

console.log(listarLog);
```

Comment: Consegui aqui com sua ajuda, muito obrigado!